# How to insert rows in MS Access from query that finds unmatched records using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010, executenonquery

I have 2 tables 'tbl_Images' and 'tbl_ImagesDetails'.  The 1st table has ImageID's which are not found in the 2nd table.

I made a query that first, finds unmatched records, and it then adds the resulting rows to the second table.

If I run the query inside Access 2010 it asks for confirmation and then the rows are added.

However, if I run it from VB.net it does not add any row and there's no error message.  Here's the code:

```
Dim strsql As String = "INSERT INTO tbl_ImagesDetails ( ImageID )
SELECT tbl_Images.ImageID
FROM tbl_Images LEFT JOIN tbl_ImagesDetails ON tbl_Images.[ImageID] = tbl_ImagesDetails.[ImageID]
WHERE (((tbl_Images.ImageID) Like 'ZOOMED*') 
AND ((tbl_ImagesDetails.ImageID) Is Null));"        
'Debug.Print(strsql)

Dim MyConn As New OleDbConnection(connString)
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(strsql, MyConn)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

If Not MyConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then MyConn.Open()

Dim iResult As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Return iResult
```

The query above should return 9 rows, but iResult = 0

My questions:

1. Is the confirmation dialog getting in the way? If so how do I override using vb code?
2. Does ExecuteNonQuery() allow inserting multiple rows in one go?
3. How can I insert rows which are the result of another query (i.e. within the same query)?

Comment: Something I just found:  In Access I  was wondering the difference between 'View' (the one with grid icon) and 'Run' (the one with exclamation).  If I click View it only shows grid with the 9 rows, if I click exclamation it adds the rows.  Is there a vb code to make it 'run' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Is the confirmation dialog getting in the way? If so how do I override using vb code?

Ans: No confirmation box if you are executing commands through code i.e. vb.net

2) Does ExecuteNonQuery() allow inserting multiple rows in one go?

Ans: Yes

3) How can I insert rows which are the result of another query (i.e. within the same query)?

I think you need to check the results/records fetched by query in vb.net, may be not getting any record. Better to write a function to check records fetched. Otherwise it seems okay.

Hope this helps!

Comment: To check the records fetched do you mean to 1) run a separate query or 2) add another command to existing query?  How to do the second one ?  Thanks.

Comment: First part (check records in select query) is for testing purpose. I suspect, that query may not be fetching any record. I don't have MS-Access locally, therefore can't do actual testing myself. Thanks

Comment: You're right it's not returning records.  Now let me see where the roadblock is...

Comment: Great, at least you figured out where problem is. Glad to help you, don't forget to accept it as answer and vote up, so that others can also get help from it. Thanks

Comment: It's working now.  The culprit was the filter in the Where statement:  Like 'ZOOMED*' . While testing, if a complete ImageID was used it works, if using asterisk it does not.  So I added the table that classifies the images by number, and used that number as filter instead of using a wildcard.  Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Answer accepted but my vote does not show cos I have less than 15 points, sorry about that.

Comment: No worries J. Thank you, glad to help you.